# CSS submenu does not display for onhover

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, onhover

I am creating a sidebar menu for my site. I have a onhover issue.

Hovering starting from the first top menu item ("Veggies") which then opens Veggies submenu items as expected.

Then as I attempt to hover from Veggies submenu item ("Green Beans") to the second top menu item ("Fruits"), it does not hover over Fruits and therefore does not open the Fruits submenu items.

I included a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/5v76d08q/4/

I believe I either need to set the position or height property somewhere but don't know where to set it to make it work.

```css
.list-group {
  display: inline-block;
}

.list-group-submenu {
  display: none;
 }

.list-group-submenu a.list-group-item {
  color: #141C35;
  background-color: #557c83;
}

.list-group-submenu:hover,
[id^=da]:hover + .list-group-submenu {
  display: block;
}

a.list-group-item:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background-color: #008080;
}
```

```html
<div id="sidebar-wrapper" style="margin-top: 51px;">
  <div id="MainMenu">
    <div id="MainMenu1">
      <div class="list-group">
        <a id="da2" href="#demo1" class="list-group-item">
          <span >Veggies </span>
        </a>
        <div id="demo1" class="list-group-submenu" style="">
          <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
            <span >Broccoli</span>
          </a>
          <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
            <span >Spinach</span>
          </a>
          <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
            <span >Green Beans</span>
          </a>
        </div>
        <a id="da3" href="#demo2" class="list-group-item">
          <span >Fruits </span>
         </a>
        <div id="demo2" class="list-group-submenu">
          <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
          <span >Mango </span>
          </a>
          <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
          <span >Cherry </span>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I expect that when I hover from Veggies submenu item Green Bean to Fruits, it should hover over Fruits and also open Fruits submenu items.

I would prefer a pure CSS solution.

Thanks!

Comment: It doesn't hover the fruits as your other menu closes so it moves the fruits back up and out of the mouse position, there isn't any nice way to solve that due to your menu jumping about

Comment: That is exactly the issue. Thanks for the response and trying it out. I was hoping someone could Somehow remove the display none/block property and instead use a combination of height and transition properties to slow down the closing of the veggies submenu which may allow enough time for the mouse position to hover over fruits or another solution. I tried what I described but it didn't work.

Comment: Most horizontal menus with hover sub menus would open them out to the side, otherwise use some sort of js solution to avoid this problem.  Guess you could try using a transition delay with your transition, that way it gives you the amount of delay time to hover on the fruits, but say your veggie menu is a lot bigger than your fruit sub menu, your cursor may still end off the bottom of the fruits sub when the transition finishes and therefore could cause the fruits to close (and maybe open some other sub if there are more than 2 items) which isn't great ux